# 'set-sized' criterion for injectivity in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, injective-module

To detect an injective object in $R-\mathbf{Mod}$, it suffices to test for only **set-sized** collection of objects, by Baer's criterion. How do we do this for an arbitrary abelian category? [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/000Z) says that for any abelian category with enough injectives, we can find a small abelian full subcategory with enough injectives, including the desired set-sized collection of objects, such that the inclusion functor is exact, and conserves and reflects injectives. I came up with a way to achieve this without finding the general set-sized injectivity criterion. The desired category is usually constructed by making intermediate steps $X_0, X_1, \ldots$ and taking the union. For each step $X_n$, we can append the witnesses for non-injectivity of non-injective objects of $X_n$ to the next step $X_{n + 1}$. Apart from this, is there any general set-sized injectivity criterion? so that we could just include them at first without appending the witnesses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general there is no set of objects that suffices to test injectivity.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of functors from ordinals to abelian groups that are nonzero only on a set of ordinals. I.e., an object $F$ assigns an abelian group $F(\alpha)$ to each ordinal $\alpha$ and a homomorphism $f_{\alpha,\beta}:F(\alpha)\to F(\beta)$ for each pair of ordinals $\alpha\leq\beta$ such that $f_{\beta,\gamma}f_{\alpha,\beta}=f_{\alpha,\gamma}$ whenever $\alpha\leq\beta\leq\gamma$, and such that there is some $\alpha$ such that $\beta\geq\alpha\Rightarrow F(\beta)=0$. And a morphism $F\to G$ is a collection of homomorphisms $F(\alpha)\to G(\alpha)$ such that the obvious squares commute.

Then $\mathcal{C}$ is an abelian category (locally small because of the restriction on when $F(\alpha)\neq0$).

It is easy to see that the functor $S_{\alpha}$, where $S_{\alpha}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S_{\alpha}(\beta)=0$ for $\beta\neq\alpha$, is not injective. But if you pick any set $\mathcal{F}$ of objects, then there is some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $F(\beta)=0$ for every $F\in\mathcal{F}$ and every $\beta\geq\alpha$.  So there are no nonzero morphisms $F\to S_{\alpha}$ for $F\in\mathcal{F}$, and so the fact that $S_{\alpha}$ is not injective can't be detected using only the objects of $\mathcal{F}$.

After posting the example above, I remembered hearing about some rather interesting related results involving less contrived categories than the one above.

It follows from Lemma 2.5 in [this recent paper of Šaroch and Trlifaj](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03749) that if $R$ is a non-perfect ring, then it is independent of ZFC (the usual axioms of set theory) whether in the category of $R$-modules there is a set of epimorphisms that suffice to test projectivity. [Actually, this was proved in a much earlier paper of Trlifaj, but the statement in the paper I've linked to is less technical.]

This means that it is independent of ZFC whether the opposite category of the category of abelian groups answers the question in the OP!

Comment: Is the category having a set of generators a sufficient condition?

Comment: @egreg See the addition to my answer. It is consistent with ZFC that the opposite category of the category of abelian groups is a counterexample, and that has a set of generators.